# spring boot controller not scaned correctly

Tags: spring-boot

I'm definitely having problems with mapping, I created a simple application in spring boot, but the mapping is wrong, here is my code:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example"})
public class DemopApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemopApplication2.class, args);
        System.out.println("erffffggggggggggggf");
    }

}


package com.example.demo.jjj;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/hanoipp")
public class Omp {
    @RequestMapping("/smm")
    String welcome() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and I have a simple html file called index.html in template, but this doesn't work
my log file is:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

2020-10-05 10:53:07.911  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemopApplication2       : Starting DemopApplication2 on ACER-3DF47200 with PID 6380 (D:\oneDr\OneDrive - OFPPT\Data\training IT\jee\demop\target\classes started by user in D:\oneDr\OneDrive - OFPPT\Data\training IT\jee\demop)
2020-10-05 10:53:07.916  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemopApplication2       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-05 10:53:07.989  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-10-05 10:53:07.990  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-10-05 10:53:09.107  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
2020-10-05 10:53:09.120  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-10-05 10:53:09.120  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2020-10-05 10:53:09.195  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-10-05 10:53:09.195  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1205 ms
2020-10-05 10:53:09.412  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-05 10:53:09.597  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-10-05 10:53:09.642  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-05 10:53:09.660  INFO 6380 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemopApplication2       : Started DemopApplication2 in 2.088 seconds (JVM running for 2.476)
erffffggggggggggggf
2020-10-05 10:53:11.645  INFO 6380 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-05 10:53:11.646  INFO 6380 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-05 10:53:11.653  INFO 6380 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
```

Comment: when I add thyeleaf plugin, it works fine, when I remove it it deosn't work

Answer (score 0):

Static html files go to `static`, not `template`.

Everything in `static` is directly passed to the client.

Without thymeleaf, you don't have a server-side parser for html files.

The `template` directory is template files that are parsed and those produce the data the client receives.

> when I add thyeleaf plugin, it works fine, when I remove it it deosn't work
> Thymeleaf works with `html` files in the `template` directory. Those files are then parsed server-side and thymeleaf tags/attributes will be converted to html.

If you have thymeleaf available and use normal html files, those will just be sent to the client without being changed.

Comment: even when i add some js to my index.html, still the problem is there

Comment: I still have the problem unfortunately

Comment: If you have a file `static/abc.js`, you can just reference `abc.js` from the html file. You do not need a controller for this.

Comment: I have the same probleme with a complexe spring boot project with lots of views, javascript and CSS, I want to work with controllers

Comment: Controllers shouldn't be used for static content but you can create a controller that reads the file manually from the resources.